# Yii: Render action using different layout than controller's layout

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

In Yii, is there a way to render a single action using a different `layout` than that defined for the controller? I have an action that I would like to format differently from the rest, and it's not clear from the documentation if that's possible.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I believe on that action you could just call the `$layout` variable.

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
    $this->layout = 'nameOfYourAltLayout';
}
```

The instructions in the link below indicate that you will have to set this variable for every action since you can't just set the default public variable and expect the other actions to default back to this.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/28/how-to-implement-multiple-page-layouts-in-an-application/

**::Edit::**

It seems the best practice here is to define the `$layout` variable in the view script for the particular action that calls it.  For example, if your action calls `viewscriptone.php` then the viewscriptone view file would contain:

```
$this->layout = 'nameOfYourAltLayout';
```

It makes more sense to override here rather than in the controller action. However, as LDG said, if the layout is conditional you should probably keep it in the controller.  This information can still be found in the link above under the "Using Layouts" section of the page.

Comment: +1 - I recommend downloading the pdf manual and blog example pdf from here. http://www.yiiframework.com/download/ its listed as documentation.

Comment: Nick, I'm a little new to SO.  What does the +1 shorthand mean?

Comment: I guess that makes sense about defining the layout in the view, depending on the specifics of your application. If the layout of a particular view is conditional, I would keep the logic in the controller. However, being able to put it in a particular view as an exception/override is certainly nice, as is the fact that you even _can_ do this in Yii, as apposed to some other frameworks.

Comment: @Idg, the conditional point is completely valid.  Thank you for bringing it up.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @k to the z - +1 is just me saying I agree with the post and I am throwing my weight behind it to. So that anyone reading it knows that its not just one person talking rubbish but other people (i.e. me) agree.

Answer (score 5):

That wiki entry does a pretty good job in describing how to use layouts, definitely worth a read. I do think you can set a layout default at the start of your controller class and then override that within a particular action function without having to define layout in each action, at least it's worked for me. You can also use the [beforeAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) function for any complex situations. And, as you may already know, you can use renderPartial to bypass the layout entirely.

Comment: Since the layout pertains to rendering views, IMO, beforeRender() is a more appropriate place than beforeAction().